# Error getting information from two tables for editing - one-to-one relationship. C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Friends, I'm a beginner and I'm having a hard time getting information from the database of two tables with a one-to-one relationship

I'm currently getting this error:

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

---

**Error**

InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'LojaVirtual.Models.person', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'LojaVirtual.Models.ViewModels.Student.PersonAddressViewModel'.

---

I tried to replace it with PersonAddressViewModel, but I get an error stating that it is not a database table. I created it only as an intermediate class. How can I get the data?

I have the "person" and "addresses" table.

below I have the two models for "person" and "address".

person.cs

```
namespace LojaVirtual.Models
{
    public class person
    {
        public int id_person { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }
        public string confirmpassword { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("id_person")]
        [JsonIgnore]
        public address Address { get; set; }
    }
}
```

address.cs

```
namespace LojaVirtual.Models
{
    public class address
    {
        [Key]
        public int id_address { get; set; }
        public string city { get; set; }
        public string state { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("person")]
        public int? id_person { get; set; }
        public virtual person Person { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I created an intermediate class.
PersonAddress.cs

```
namespace LojaVirtual.Models.ViewModels.Student
{
    public class PersonAddressViewModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int id_person { get; set; }         
        public string name{ get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }
        public string confirmpassword { get; set; }

        public string city { get; set; }
        public string state{ get; set; }

    }
}
```

The registration is done normally in the two tables, but I have difficulty in bringing the data filled in with the values ​​of the two tables for editing.

This is my editing method:

```
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Update()
        {

            person person = _clientRepository.getperson(_loginPerson.GetClient().id_person);
            return View(person);
        }
```

My View
Update.cshtml

```
@model LojaVirtual.Models.ViewModels.Student.PersonAddressViewModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Update";
}

<h2>Atualizar</h2>

<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Atualizar">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="id_person" />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="email" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="email" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="email" class="text-danger"></span>
.
.
.
.

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="city" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="city" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="city" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="state" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="state" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="state" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
```

EDIT

```
        public person getperson(int id_person)
        {
            return _db.person.Find(id_person);
        }
```

I appreciate if anyone can help.
Any comment is very welcome!

Comment: I would suggest you to study EF and navigation properties. Your second class is an unnecessary one IMHO. I would also suggest you to study C# naming conventions. While you are not strictly entitled to it, it greatly simplifies the readability at least.

Comment: You have the entity models and the view models. You need to map one to the other. If you ever heard of Automapper, that's what it's for, or you can write the mapping yourself.

Comment: Hey, I started reading. Thanks for the feedback! If you could tell me what needs to be changed in the error-based code, I would also appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Update` view expect a `PersonAddressViewModel` type model, so the Update action needs to return a instance of PersonAddressViewModel to it. As @insane_developer metioned, you can use some mapping library, such as Automapper. It’s okay if you haven’t heard that, you can simply map it one by one.

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Update()
{

    person person = _clientRepository.getperson(_loginPerson.GetClient().id_person);
    var personAddressViewModel = new PersonAddressViewModel()
    {
        id_person = person.id_person;
        name= person.name;
        email = person.email;
        password = person.password;
        confirmpassword = person.confirmpassword;
        city = (person.Address == null) ? null : person.Address.city;
        state= (person.Address == null) ? null : person.Address.state
    };
    
    return View(personAddressViewModel);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm getting this error:

System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
LojaVirtual.Models.Person.Address.get retornou null.

Comment: Hi @EdrianBiagi, I forgot the case that `Address` property maybe null. We should have a check for null reference. like this: `city = (person.Address== null) ? null : person.Address.city; state= (person.Address== null) ? null : person.Address.state`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. the error has been resolved, but the address fields have not been filled out.

Comment: @EdrianBiagi, the person is come from `_clientRepository.getperson()` this method, do you load the related address in the method? EF Core need to use `.Include()` method to get the related entities. See the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager).